# recover deleted files that are still in memory

Tags: data-recovery, nodejs

I accidentally deleted a folder of .js files with FileZilla, but they are still loaded in a Nodejs app. Is it possible to recover them?

Comment: When files are deleted the file entry on the fs is erased, but if files were in-use, the inodes (data blocks with file contents) are not freed until after the now-deleted-file is closed by all apps using them.  This is what you're seeing  (or it's a cached entry [not open file] where it'll fail if you try and use them).  If the app with the file open has a save/copy function it can copy the data or can save to the same file name and it'll re-create a file entry.

Comment: Find the process for the app in /proc/123/ directory where 123 is pid of that process. If the files are held open, you could still cat the open file descriptors. If they are cache like guiver said - there is no way to recover , at least I dont know one

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to [dump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/memdump.1.html) (or use [another tool](https://superuser.com/questions/164960/how-do-i-dump-physical-memory-in-linux)) the whole memory, and then analyse your dump with [volatile](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility) to recover your files.

You can even recover files in RAM that were used by a process, which was killed, an example [here](https://volatility-labs.blogspot.com/2013/05/movp-ii-21-rsa-private-keys-and.html).

If you are in a virtual machine, you do a snapshot instead of the dump, and then use volatile too.

Easier and more classic, if you can stop the activities on your hard drive, you can dump the whole drive and recover the data with [R-studio](https://www.r-studio.com/) for instance.